# Allow implicit casting for types with the same underlying structure

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, c++14, c++17

I've got several structures in my code which all have

- one member with the same type, e.g. `std::pair` or `cv::Point2d`
- different functions, e.g. getters/setters named differently in each struct

Example:

```
struct CartesianCoordinates {
    std::pair<double, double> xy;

    void x(double val) { xy.first = val; }
    void y(double val) { xy.second = val; }
    double x() const { return xy.first; }
    double y() const { return xy.second; }
};

struct GeographicCoordinates {
    std::pair<double, double> xy;

    void longtitude(double val) { xy.first = val; }
    void lattitude(double val) { xy.second = val; }
    double longtitude() const { return xy.first; }
    double lattitude() const { return xy.second; }
};
```

Now I want to be able to convert between those types *implicitly*, like this:

```
CartesianCoordinates returnCartesian()
{
    CartesianCoordinates c;
    c.x(5);
    c.y(-13);
    return c;
}

void getGeographicCoordinates(const GeographicCoordinates& c) {
    std::cout << c.longtitude() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    getGeographicCoordinates(returnCartesian());
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this without

- defining cast operators (I don't want to define those in every struct, 1:1),
- providing base class for those structures (if I don't want to define any base class)?

In fact `reinterpret_cast`/pointers should work, but do any modern C++ mechanism exist that I am not aware of and that could help me to solve it with least structures implementation overhead, just using the fact that **all structures have the same structure inside**?

Comment: Will the single member always be named the same?

Comment: It sounds like you want to interpret one type's `xy` member as another type's `xy`. Consider whether or not this would actually be desirable. The value of a `CartesianCoordinates::xy` doesn't mean the same thing as a value of a `GeographicCoordinates::xy` and interpreting one type's value as another type's value isn't logically consistent. The question itself is interesting, but the suggested application seems like a poor design decision.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want this example to output 5 or the longitude of the result of a logical conversion to `GeographicCoordinates`.

Comment: I would hate to work on codebase where programmers have made such structs and then mechanically reinterpret between those. In actual reality geographical coordinate data from different external origins and/or to different external targets is different (see GEOREF, UTM, MGRS, GARS and USNG). Programmers should not add to it by making lot of dumb differently named structs that are in essence just a pair of doubles with unknown unit, accuracy and validity. Instead they should use one (and only one) real class and convert to other formats maximally close to external interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as long as you don't want to transform the data in the data member, and as long as the member is always named the same thing, you can use a template conversion operator.  Then you use SFINAE to constrain the template for only types that have the named member that is the same type as the named member of the class.   Adding

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::pair<double, double>, decltype(std::declval<T&>().xy)>>* = nullptr>
operator T() { return T{xy}; }
```

To both classes allows them to be converted to one another and allows

```
int main()
{
    getGeographicCoordinates(returnCartesian());
}
```

to run ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e2b8c192d3808b3))

---

If the classes will not use the same member variable name then you could have them all surface a typedef that is named the same that is the type of the data member and use that.  That would look like

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<my_variable_typedef, typename T::my_variable_typedef>>* = nullptr>
operator T() { return T{xy}; }
```

Comment: You also need to add ctor from pair to the types.

Comment: @Yakk Why?  They are an aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by defining an access interface to the members.

I would suggest you reuse the `get` idiom and define templated (on an index) `get` free functions for all the structs you want this behaviour to work on.

Then you must define the functions that should work on all these types in a similar manner as templates, and access the members through the `get` interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without lots of per-structure boilerplate.

> In fact reinterpret_cast/pointers should work

Not actually true.  You can reinterpret from struct to pair using the fact that the pair is the first element in the standard layout structure, but you can only reinterpret from pair to struct *if that structure type is actually there*.

If an object of the structure type isn't there, the reinterpret from pair to struct is undefined behavior.

Here is an attempt to do this in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with minimal boilerplate while remaining generic.  We do inherit from an empty CRTP empty parent type to inject some friends and conversion operators.  Also, we have to add some code that exposes the members of each to the CRTP parent.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct tie_same;

template<class A, class B>
using tie_check = typename tie_same<A,B>::type;

template<class D>
struct structured {
  friend auto as_tie( structured<D>& s ) {
    auto& self = static_cast<D&>(s);
    auto members = get_members(self);
    return std::apply( [&self](auto...pm) {
      return std::tie( (self.*pm)... );
    }, members );
  }
  friend auto as_tie( structured<D> const& s ) {
    auto& self = static_cast<D const&>(s);
    auto members = get_members(self);
    return std::apply( [&self](auto...pm) {
      return std::tie( (self.*pm)... );
    }, members );
  }

  template<class T,
    std::enable_if_t<
      tie_check<T,D>{},
      bool
    > = true
  >
  operator T() const& {
    T tmp;
    as_tie(tmp) = as_tie( *this );
    return tmp;
  }
};

template<class A, class B>
struct tie_compatible {
  template<class X>
  using tie_type = decltype( as_tie( std::declval<X>() ) );
  using type = std::is_same< tie_type<A&>, tie_type<B&> >;
};
```

a bit tricky but does the job.

To support this system in a type `X`, you need to:

1. inherit `X` from `structured<X>`.
2. Implement `auto members(X const& x)` that returns a tuple of pointer-to-members you care about.
3. Have a default constructor for your target type, and be ok with construction-through-assignment.

Here are your types augmented with this feature:

```
struct CartesianCoordinates: structured<CartesianCoordinates> {
  std::pair<double, double> xy;

  friend auto get_members( CartesianCoordinates const& self ) {
    return std::make_tuple( &CartesianCoordinates::xy );
  }

  void x(double val) { xy.first = val; }
  void y(double val) { xy.second = val; }
  double x() const { return xy.first; }
  double y() const { return xy.second; }
};

struct GeographicCoordinates: structured<GeographicCoordinates> {
  std::pair<double, double> xy;

  friend auto get_members( GeographicCoordinates const& self ) {
    return std::make_tuple( &GeographicCoordinates::xy );
  }

  void longtitude(double val) { xy.first = val; }
  void lattitude(double val) { xy.second = val; }
  double longtitude() const { return xy.first; }
  double lattitude() const { return xy.second; }
};
```

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) just implement your own `notstd::apply`.

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) it gets annoying due to the lack of return type deduction.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
   noexecpt(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
   -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
   { return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

`RETURNS` can patch over that pain a bit.

```
auto foo()
  RETURNS( 1+2 )
```

replacing

```
auto foo() {
  return 1+2;
}
```

sometimes works.  (There are important differences still, but what can you do)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your answer looks like it blown up compared to NathanOlivier's, because he uses aggregate initialization and your answer is more general? Or am I missing something else? It's interesting to understand the difference between one-liner utility and a template glitter bomb (Sorry for the comparison, I like it but, boy, my teammates wouldn't want to maintain it.)

Comment: @luk32 his requires that SFINAE conversion operator written on each leaf class and that member names match exactly.  Mine requires inheritance and the members friend function.